# Eliminating matching values in a SQL result set

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, grouping, matching, suppress

I have a table with a list of transactions (invoices and credits) and I need to get a list of all the rows where the invoices and credits don't match up.

eg

```
user     product    value
bill     ThingA     200
jim      ThingA    -200
sue      ThingB     100
liz      ThingC      50
```

I only want to see the third and fourth rows, as the values of the others match off.

I can do this if I select product, sum(value)
...
group by product
having sum(value) <> 0

which works well, but I want to return the user name as well.

As soon as I add the user to the select, I need to group by it as well, which messes it up as the amounts don't match up by user AND product.

Any ideas ?  I am using MS SQL 2000...

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
  SELECT tab2.user, product, sum_val
  FROM 
     (SELECT product, SUM(value) sum_val 
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY product HAVING SUM(value) <> 0) tab1 
  INNER JOIN your_table tab2 
  ON tab1.product = tab2.product
```

Comment: This will not work if the table has two positive transaction for some product made by two different user. Still is a good solution given the OP context tho!

Comment: I just used OP query in my answer so that OP can use his/her original query in his/her solution....

Answer (score 0):

@LolCoder solution is good, but given a context where you have "Thing B" with a "100" value by both "sue" and "liz", you could be able to retrieve the following resultset with my query :

```
| product | value | users    |
+----------------------------+
| Thing B | 200   | sue, liz |
```

Here is the query :

```
select product
      ,sum(value) as value
      ,Stuff(( select ',' + convert(varchar(40), SQ.user)
                 from YourTable SQ
                where Q.product = SQ.product
                for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as users
  from YourTable Q
 group by Q.product
```